# Azure Pipeline Error in generating code coverage results

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage

I am trying to generate code coverage results for my .net core project using Azure Pipelines.

This is my pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
- sonar-analysis

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  submodules: true

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '6.x'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--verbosity n'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura'
  
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

I am able to run my Tests successfully and it shows Test Results in Tests tab.

However, I am not able to get the code coverage report.

I get following in my dotnet test task:

> Data collector 'XPlat code coverage' message:
> [coverlet]System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection' from
> assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz'.    at
> Coverlet.Collector.DataCollection.CoverletCoverageCollector.GetDefaultServiceCollection(TestPlatformEqtTrace
> eqtTrace, TestPlatformLogger logger, String testModule)    at
> Coverlet.Collector.DataCollection.CoverletCoverageCollector.OnSessionStart(Object
> sender, SessionStartEventArgs sessionStartEventArgs) in
> /_/src/coverlet.collector/DataCollection/CoverletCoverageCollector.cs:line
> 132.

Since there is not coverage.cobertura.xml file generated, I get following in Publish Code Coverage results task:

> ##[warning]No code coverage results were found to publish.

I believe this could be the reason of coverage xml file not getting generated. This is strange because the same pipeline works for other projects.

What could be the reason of this issue and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to resolve this by upgrading Coverlet version from 3.1.2 to 3.2.0.

FYI this Issue on GH - https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/1390

Comment: Glad that the issue can be fixed, and thanks for sharing the answer. Maybe, you can mark your answer as the solution of this case. This could be helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.